# Continuum of Lagrange multipliers, duality gap, and minimax theorem

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, linear-programming, duality, global-optimization

Suppose I have a linear optimization problem involving random variables on some (infinite) probability space $\Omega$. For example, need to maximize expectation $E[Q]$ of random variable $Q$ subject to some linear constraints. I may have "single" constrains such as $E[XQ]\geq 0$ for some given random variable $X$, but also constraints like $0\leq Q \leq 1$, which encodes uncountably many constraints in the form $0 \leq Q(w) \leq 1$, $w \in \Omega$. I now can write a Lagrangian. For single constraint, I can add one real Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$. For continuum of constraints $0 \leq Q(w) \leq 1$, $w \in \Omega$, I need one multiplier $\Lambda(w)$ for each $w \in \Omega$, or, equivalently, random variable $\Lambda$ as a mupliplier. Thus, my problem is equivalent to
$$
\sup_{Q\geq 0} \inf_{\lambda \geq 0, \Lambda \geq 0} (E[Q]+E[\Lambda(1-Q)]+\lambda E[XQ]).
$$
I now would like to interchange inf and sup to move to the dual problem. However, standard minimax theorems like Sion's minimax theorem seem to be not applicable because sets over which we optimize are not compact. The classical duality theorem for linear programming (as well as saddle point theory for finitely many Lagrange multipliers) is also not applicable because we have infinitely many constraints. Nevertheless, I assume there should be standard tools to prove the possibility of interchanging inf and sup (or, equivalently, the absence of duality gap) in examples like this. In there any general theorem for which the example above is a special case? Of course, the theorem should have some (preferably easy-to-check) conditions, because the duality gap may be non-zero in general.